# OAuthException with post action only in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, asp.net-mvc-3, facebook-c#-sdk

In my fb application I calling a post action

```
$.post("http://localhost:3435/Home/Try?id=123&x=1");
```

My action

```cs
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Try(string id, int x)
{
  //post on my wall
  var client = new FacebookWebClient();
  dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
  //...
  dynamic result = client.Post("me/feed", parameters);
  //...
}
```

In FF and chrome this works as expected. Posts to wall. But in Internet Explore I get an exception.
(OAuthException) An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.

Some answers in similar question suggested to get the acces token from the FacebookSetting, but this seems to be null when debugged. I find this very strange since this works in FF and Mozilla.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to manually maintain the signed_request for post backs or ajax requests.

Pass signed_request as a parameter to your ajax post request.

More details at http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/discussions/251878 and http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/discussions/250820

Comment: it is signed_request. signed_request contains additional information other than access_token which might be required for the post back.

Comment: Simply, adding the access_token as a parameter to each post helped,  as suggested. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

hmm check if IE has flash installed for x-domain communication, if not, try installing, also try hitting the apps.facebook.com/yourapp instead of going directly to the iframe

oh 1 other thing it could be if it's an iframe, is 3rd party cookies, try adding header('P3P: CP=HONK');
 to your php code

Comment: What does flash have to do with this?  
When I used apps.facebook.com/myapp the action wasn't reached at all in IE.  I'm not using php. Asp MVC-3.

Thanks