# OAuthException Facebook C# SDK ie9

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I am using the following code in my facebook application. The when loading the application in facebook has no problem in chrome/firefox/ie8. When it runs in IE9 it is reporting that OAuthException has been thrown.

```
public string GetFacebookId() {
            if (!FacebookWebContext.Current.IsAuthorized())
                return string.Empty;

            var client = new FacebookWebClient();

            dynamic me = client.Get("me");
            return me.id;
        }
```

```
(OAuthException) An active access token must be used to query 
information about the current user.
```

any suggestions would be appreciated.

thanks.

**EDIT:**

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.init({
            appId: '@(Facebook.FacebookApplication.Current.AppId)', // App ID
            //channelURL: '//facebook.thefarmdigital.com.au/moccona/premium/FacebookChannel/', // Channel File
            status: true, // check login status
            cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
            oauth: true, // enable OAuth 2.0
            xfbml: true  // parse XFBML
        });
        FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow();
    };


$(function () {
        $('#custom_login').click(function () {
            FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
                if (response.authResponse) {
                    //should never get here as controller will pass to logged in page
                } else {
                    FB.login(function (response) {
                        if (response.authResponse) {
                            window.location = '@(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Replace(Request.Url.PathAndQuery, ""))' + $('#custom_login').attr('href');
                        } else {
                            window.location = '@(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Replace(Request.Url.PathAndQuery, ""))' + $('#custom_login').attr('dataFail');
                        }
                    }, { scope: 'publish_stream' });
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
```

Comment: What do you mean with `When it runs in IE9` ?

Comment: this is a sample of code that is run in a larger applicaion. The  method is used to return the users facebook id. when browsing the app in firefox the id is returned. When browsing in IE9 it returns the exception above.

Comment: do you need more info maybe? or do you just want to downvote cos your are having a bad day?

Comment: No, Maybe you may want to use a better terminology.  When you say `When it runs in IE9` I understand that you have a plugin that runs in the context of the browser. 'App' is a broad term and doesn't mean generally a web aplication

Comment: ok so suggest some better terminology

Comment: I see that a "-1" resulted in a better question with your update.

Comment: `ok so suggest some better terminology` So you want me to ask a better question for yourself? :)

Comment: lb you are a bit if a dick hey.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with FB's C# SDK, but judging from the code you gave, it does not seem that you are doing any user authentication with FB. It might be that it works in Chrome and Firefox only because you are somehow already logged into your FB app in those browsers.

Comment: thanks for the post:. the authorization works in the other browsers. I have updated my question to include the fbinit and request to login. I have had a look around and it seems that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7224698/oauthexception-with-post-action-only-in-ie is a similar problem to mine.. will let you know how it goes.